# Include Wifi menu in android application

Tags: android, wifi, segment

In my android application I want to create a segment where the user can connect with the WIFI. All avaiable WIFI Networks are supposed to be shown in a list where the user can be connected to a WIFI network just by tapping the required network.

I hope you can help me:D

Comment: We are not a code writing service, try to google search what you asked and you will see that there are plenty of results.

Comment: Tried looking for libraries like this - https://github.com/nishkarsh/android-wificonnect . Please do a thorough search before asking a question.

Comment: @Martin De Simone Can you may give me some keywords to google for, becaue I could not find anything